# PHP - Get the child class method name in the parent scope

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, methods

How can I get the child class method name from the parent scope in a non-static context?

Its simple to get the current method name using `__METHOD__` magic constant, but I'm trying to get the method which initiated the request.

`get_class($this)` returns the caller class in superclass scope. A similar implementation for getting method is required.

For example:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        // Here I want know which method initiated the call.
        // In current scenario its the method foo() of the B class.
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {

    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->foo();
```

Comment: what does B::foo have to do with the parent's constructor?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? The comment you added to A's constructor seems to indicate that you want to output B::foo, but the constructor is called before foo.

Comment: @MightyPork it has nothing to do with the constructor.

Comment: @mtinsley added more detail. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of how objects are instantiated. The constructor is called when you create a new object, not when a method of that object is called. Using the code you provided, A's constructor would be called when this line is executed:

```
$b = new B();
```

By the time `$b->foo()` is called, the object has already been created and the constructor will not be called again. Your request to "know which method initiated the call" doesn't make sense because a method call does not initialize an object.

If for some reason you need to determine an object's type in its parent's constructor you can use the `is_a($object, $class_name)` function.

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump( is_a($this, 'B') );
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {

    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->foo();
```

The above code will output: `bool(true)`

You can also use the `get_called_class()` function to get an object's actual class. Note that this differs from the `__CLASS__` constant which will be the class that the current method belongs to, regardless of whether or not it is an instance of an implementing class.

See [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Doing it the right way.**

```
class A {
    public function bar() {
        $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);
        echo $trace[count($trace) - 1]['function'];

        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        $this->bar();
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->foo();
```

**Results**

```
foo
bar
```

In `debug_backtrace` parameters, `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS` omits the "args" index, and thus all the function/method arguments, to save memory. Second parameter limits the stack frames to `2`.